# How to get cssSelector to Find a Element in IE 9

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors

How to find cssSelector using developer tool in IE9?

Comment: F12 Developer Tools != Selenium. You may be confusing the two. (Which you shouldn't be - nowhere does IE call its developer tools "Selenium".)

Answer (score 3):

Pro-tip, you shouldn't be using tools to "find" or "create" selectors for you - why? Tools are going to give you the *basic* selector, which is not necessarily the *best* one.

Therefore, you need to look at and understand the CSS selector [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and actually create them yourself.

However, once you've created the selectors yourself it is quite easy to actually "run" them in IE's Developer Tools. You just need to mimic what Selenium does.

Example selector: **#someID > div.something**

In IE's Developer Tools, open up the Console, and type in:

```
document.querySelector("selector")
```

Which, in my example, is:

```
document.querySelector("#someID > div.something")
```

This is equivalent to your `.FindElement` calls, and as for your `.FindElements` calls:

```
document.querySelectorAll("selector")
```

Which, in my example, is:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#someID > div.something")
```

The result you get back, is what (in theory) Selenium should also be finding.

Comment: +1, I'd definitely reference this answers whenever I see someone's looking for xpath/css selector auto-generators and doesn't want to learn. As well as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4173779/1177636)

Comment: Thanks Arran, is there a way I can do `Copy CSS Path` in Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0):

You should use firefox and add ons firebug and firepath to get the right xpath. When executing tests define the browser internet explorer or chrome or firefox or etc instead

firebug https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: He isn't looking for an XPath tool. He is using CSS selectors.

Comment: Firepath will also do CSS selectors as well as XPath.